# R - colouring scatterplot points

Tags: r

[image]

Hi there, I'm wondering why my code below makes the legend coloured, but the dots themselves are not:

```
# dataset <- data.frame(IDName, Value, Setpoints)
# dataset <- unique(dataset)

# Paste or type your script code here:
dat <- aggregate(Value ~ Setpoints + IDName, dataset, mean)

x <- dat$Value
y <- dat$Setpoints
z <- dataset$IDName

plot(x,y, main ="Turbidity Frequency Distribution",xlab="% Time < Turbidity level", ylab="Turbidity (NTU)")

lines(spline(x,y))

palette()
legend('topleft', legend = unique(z), col = 1:3, cex = 0.8, pch = 1)

#constant lines
abline(h=c(0.1,0.15,0.3), col=c("red","pink","purple"), lty=2, lwd=3)
```

Comment: As for your previous question - some example data would help. I note your questions are not getting many answers and this is the reason. It doesn't have to come from PowerBI - anything that resembles `dataset` or `dat` would help.

Comment: theres 280million rows of data, I'm unable to get some example data easily that portrays the thing as a whole

Comment: Then make something up that resembles it.

Comment: IDName Setpoint Value (%)
Filter 01 0.16 96.1
Filter 01 0.2 96.2
Filter 01 0.3 96.428
Filter 01 2 99.603
Filter 01 2.2 99.6
Filter 02 0.16 98.8
Filter 02 0.2 98.9
Filter 02 0.3 99.049
Filter 02 2 99.194
Filter 02 2.2 99.2

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `z` is a `factor`. Then, use `col = z` when you create the plot. You will get colored points.

In your `legend` (the character values to appear in legend) to the `levels` of your `factor` `z`. In addition, set the colors based on `unique(z)` - they should match your points.

Here is the complete example. In the future, instead of putting data in a comment, please edit your question with the data. Also, you may want to consider `ggplot2` for future plotting.

```
dat <- aggregate(Value ~ Setpoints + IDName, dataset, mean)

x <- dat$Value
y <- dat$Setpoints
z <- dataset$IDName

z <- factor(z)

plot(x, y, 
     main ="Turbidity Frequency Distribution",
     xlab="% Time < Turbidity level", 
     ylab="Turbidity (NTU)",
     col = z)

lines(spline(x,y))

palette()

legend('topleft', 
       legend = levels(z), 
       col = unique(z), 
       cex = 0.8, 
       pch = 1)

#constant lines
abline(h=c(0.1,0.15,0.3), col=c("red","pink","purple"), lty=2, lwd=3)
```

**Plot**

[image: plot with colored points]

**Data**

```
dataset <- structure(list(IDName = c("Filter01", "Filter01", "Filter01", 
"Filter01", "Filter01", "Filter02", "Filter02", "Filter02", "Filter02", 
"Filter02"), Setpoints = c(0.16, 0.2, 0.3, 2, 2.2, 0.16, 0.2, 
0.3, 2, 2.2), Value = c(96.1, 96.2, 96.428, 99.603, 99.6, 98.8, 
98.9, 99.049, 99.194, 99.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer, the logic of it makes a lot of sense. Frustratingly though, when I apply it to my data the legend is coloured whereas the points remain black. I will have to look into this further, but I suspect it may be due to the aggregation of all the data whereas the sample set I gave was the already aggregated data as it was too hard to flesh out some unaggregated data.